# What is the SQL statement for the following task:

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

List those publishers who publish paperbacks and the number of paperbacks published by each. 
I'm having a difficult time with the counting the paperbacks for each publisher. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Henry Books Table Schema**

```
**author**          
    authorNum       INT             PRIMARY KEY 
    authorLast      VARCHAR(12),    
    authorFirst     VARCHAR(10)

**publisher**           
    publisherCode       CHAR(3)         PRIMARY KEY 
    publisherName       VARCHAR(25)     
    city                VARCHAR(20)

**book**            
    bookCode            CHAR(4)         PRIMARY KEY 
    title               VARCHAR(40)     
    publisherCode       CHAR(3)     
    bookType            CHAR(3)     
    paperback           ENUM('No', 'Yes') 

    CONSTRAINT book_fk_publisher 
        FOREIGN KEY (publisherCode) 
        REFERENCES publisher(publisherCode) 

**branch**      
    branchNum       INT          
    branchName      VARCHAR(50)  
    branchLocation  VARCHAR(50) 

**copy** 
    bookCode        CHAR(4)  
    branchNum       INT  
    copyNum         INT     PRIMARY KEY 
    quality         ENUM('Excellent', 'Fair', 'Good', 'Poor') 
    price           DECIMAL(8,2) 

    CONSTRAINT copy_pk 
        PRIMARY KEY (bookCode, branchNum, copyNum 
    CONSTRAINT copy_fk_book 
        FOREIGN KEY (bookCode) 
        REFERENCES book(bookCode),      
    CONSTRAINT copy_fk_branch 
        FOREIGN KEY (branchNum) 
        REFERENCES branch(branchNum) 

**wrote** 
    bookCode   CHAR(4)  
    authorNum  INT  
    sequence   INT 

    PRIMARY KEY (BookCode, AuthorNum), 
    CONSTRAINT wrote_fk_book 
        FOREIGN KEY (bookCode) 
        REFERENCES book(bookCode), 
    CONSTRAINT wrote_fk_author 
        FOREIGN KEY (authorNum) 
        REFERENCES author(authorNum)
```

This is what I have:

```
SELECT publisherName, COUNT(paperback) AS "numPaperback"
FROM publisher, book
WHERE paperback = "Yes";
```

Comment: What query you have tried so far

Comment: I do my own homework....had problem with one. Kiran.....I'll post what I have...thank you.

Comment: sounds like you are here with your homework. So how are you doing your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are new. So I will try to walk you through this...

1. Join the publisher table to the book table. They share a publisher code which appears to link them together.
2. Filter the joined table by book type using a `where` clause. You want paperbacks.
3. Perform a `group by` on publisher code and name, and then `count` the book column

Does this help get you started?

Comment: Thank you for your help....lol I posted what I had above so I wouldn't upset more people.....I'm going to try what you posted...Thank you

Comment: That's the same reason I didn't write it all out for you. It's good to show us what you have tried!

Comment: @kbball Good way to guide a beginner .I appreciate in making them do the work rather than blindly pasting the code.

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes much more sense!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **count(*)** and **Group by** for the count of paperbacks. This is how I would write the query:

```
SELECT publisherName,count(*) AS "Number of paperbacks" FROM
publisher p INNER JOIN book b WHERE
p.publisherCode=b.publisherCode AND b.paperback="Yes"
GROUP BY publisherName;
```

Comment: You need an ON in place of the WHERE, and then change the AND to a WHERE

Comment: I always use WHERE instead of ON. And it works fine. Thats why i think this may work as well.